# using variable in import command

Tags: python, variables, import

I have a variable like

```
k = os
```

If I have to import os
I can write

```
import os
```

then I get no error
But how can I import k ( k is actually `os` ) 
I tried

```
import k
```

then I got error there is no module.
I tried naming `k = 'os'` instead of `k = os`.Still I am getting the same error

**Update :**
Actually I have to `import DATABASES` variable from settings file in the environmental variable  DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE

How can I achieve this

```
from os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] import DATABASES
```

Comment: You can't use variable names in import statements.

Comment: Any good reason to use variables?

Comment: I do not understand why to downvote a reasonable question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`importlib`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/importlib.html#module-importlib) module if you want to import modules based on a string:

```
>>> import importlib
>>> os = importlib.import_module('os')
>>> os
<module 'os' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/os.pyc'>
```

When you do something like this:

```
>>> k = 'os'
>>> import k
```

then Python still looks for file named `k.py`, `k.pyc` etc not `os.py` as you intended.

Comment: Is there any reason to prefer `importlib.import_module` over the simpler `__import__`?

Comment: @MarkRansom For simple import you could use `__import__` as well, but it is recommended(`help(__import__)`)  to use `importlib.import_module` module. But when importing packages they differ slightly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `__import__` function:

```
k = 'os'
module = __import__(k)
```